# Can't read file in Lua after I moved the .love file elsewhere

Tags: file, lua, path, io, love2d

So I zipped my Love2D project and it works when I launch it in the same folder, but elsewhere my io.open doesn't work. Here's my file system:

```
...
utils
   |json.lua  <-- library I use for encoding and decoding
   |JSONHandler.lua
   |parameters.json
conf.lua
main.lua
...
```

I get my error in **JSONHandler.lua** where I have:

```
local json = require "utils/json"

Handler = {
   filename = "utils/parameters.json",
   params = {},
   ...
}

function Handler:init()
   local o = {}
   setmetatable(o, self)
   self.__index = self

   local file = io.open(self.filename, "r")
   local content = file:read("a")
   ...
```

My **file** ends up being **nil**

I tried many different relative paths for **filename** but nothing worked so I'm wondering how .love files handle paths, how should I track to my **parameters.json**?

Comment: Maybe try love.filesystem? Or you could use parameters.lua and a table for config instead.

Comment: Is `parameters.json` inside the zip archive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably works when you do not move the `.love` file because it still has access to the original files from the working directory.

Lua can not read content in zip files out of the box, but Love2d offers [love.filesystem](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.filesystem).

It also has file wrappers, but if you just want to read the content prefer [`read`](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.filesystem.read):

```
local content = love.filesystem.read(self.filename)
```

Note that you can only read files in the love zip, in the working directory and in the save directory.